# Google Drive - Automating creating multiple folders and documents templates

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-shared-drive

Our organization creates the same folder structure with templated documents for each job. Right now staff manually creates each folder and within those folder creates each document from a template in the organizations template gallery. Is there a simple-ish way to automate this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this if you would want to create a simple automated sheet script for it.

```
function createFolder() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var getFolderID = ss.getRange('A2').getValue();
var setFolderName = ss.getRange('B2').getValue();
var setDocName = ss.getRange('C2').getValue();
var setTemplate = ss.getRange('D2').getValue();

var drive = DriveApp;
var parentfolder = drive.getFolderById(getFolderID);
var newFolder = parentfolder.createFolder(setFolderName);
var createDoc = DocumentApp.create(setDocName);
var getDocID = createDoc.getId();
    
drive.getFileById(getDocID).moveTo(newFolder).setContent(setTemplate);
}
```

What this does is I created a sheet template like this: [image: sample]

Set the Parent Folder ID on cell A2 which you can find on the folder URL "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/{parentfolderID}?resourcekey"

Set the folder name on cell B2, as well as the document name on C2 and your template on D2.

You can run the script by going into Tools > Script Editor, or you can assign an image to act as a button and assign the script to that image.

Running the script would result into this folder hierarchy [image]

with the value of D2 inside the Google Doc. [image]

**References:**

1. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app
2. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app
3. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet